# json_encode can not escape single quotation marks?

Tags: php, json

```
$emailFields =  array(
    array(
        'name' => 'comments', 
        'type' => 'html', 
        'content' => "ahfsd\jfh/sf's askghaskg sadf"
    ),
);
echo json_encode($emailFields);
```

The print is

```
[{
    "name": "comments",
    "type": "html",
    "content": "ahfsd\\jfh/sf's askghaskg sadf"
}]
```

Why the json_encode can not escape the `'`?

Comment: Why would it escape the `'`?

Comment: don't need too escape as you put `"` in both side of content

Comment: @JonStirling because i want to insert it into the db like the following

Comment: @JonStirling because i want to insert it into the db like the following
`$sql = "select * from a where email = '%s'"`;
`$sql = sprintf($sql,  json_encode($emailFields));`
`tep_db_query($sql);`
The `tep_db_query($sql)` is execute the sql statement
Because of the json_encode can`t escape single quotation marks,there will be an mysql error，what can i do?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to insert into the DB.

Comment: You should **never** use interpolation or concatenation in DB queries.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [JSON Docs](http://www.json.org/) say, strings in JSON are surrounded by double quotes. There is no need to escape single quote in JSON.

> A value can be a **string in double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

Also

> A **string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string.

You should escape *double* quotes in your string values.

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to convert any ` to \u0027 you can do it by using the following code:

```
json_encode($emailFields, JSON_HEX_APOS)
```

Or you can map your array and escape the apostrophe on each value.
I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and why you want to escape it, but I gave you some tools and you will decide by your self.